# _filter_or_exclude() argument after ** must be a mapping, not ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Why i get this error?

My Models.py:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from sitem.ligler.models import *
from sitem.takimlar.models import *
from sitem.futbolcular.models import *
from sitem.stadyumlar.models import *
from sitem.ligmaclari.models import *

DAKIKA_SECIMLERI = [(str(dk), str(dk)) for dk in range(1, 121)]
KART_SECIMLER = (
    ('SK','Sari Kart'),
    ('SKK','Sarıdan Kırmızı Kart'),
    ('DKK','Direk Kırmızı Kart')
)
# Create your models here.
class EvSahibiKartlar(models.Model):
    mac = models.ForeignKey(Ligmaclari)
    ev_sahibi_oyuncu = models.ForeignKey(Futbolcular, limit_choices_to = Ligmaclari.ev_sahibi_takim_kadro, related_name='Ev Sahibi Oyuncu')
    kart_tipi = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=KART_SECIMLER)
    dakika = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=4, choices=DAKIKA_SECIMLERI)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.mac

class KonukKartlar(models.Model):
    mac = models.ForeignKey(Ligmaclari)
    konuk_takim_oyuncu = models.ForeignKey(Futbolcular, limit_choices_to = Ligmaclari.konuk_takim_kadro, related_name='Konuk Takım Oyuncu')
    kart_tipi = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=KART_SECIMLER)
    dakika = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=4, choices=DAKIKA_SECIMLERI)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.mac
```

My admin.py:

```
from sitem.kartlar.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class EvSahibiKartlarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['mac']

class KonukKartlarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['mac']
admin.site.register(EvSahibiKartlar,EvSahibiKartlarAdmin)
admin.site.register(KonukKartlar,KonukKartlarAdmin)
```

Actually i want to do filter ForeignKeys...

Answer (score 3):

*Solution inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203568/2144569*

You (and also I) got this error while passing a queryset to limit_choices_to, instead directly pass the pk (i.e:`{pk__in:pks}`) and it will work :

I was getting this error while trying to remove duplicate in limit_choices_to as I was doing

```
limit_choices_to = Q(attr1=True) | Q(attr2=True) | Q(attr3=True)
```

I tried to do :

```
def my_func():
    return MyModel.objects.filter(Q(attr1=True) | Q(attr2=True) | Q(attr3=True)).distinct().all()

class HeadModel(models.Model):
    mtm = models.ManyToManyField(
        MyModel,
        limit_choices_to=my_func,
    )
```

but I got the error above as it is a queryset. Finally I did

```
def my_func():
    return {'pk__in':MyModel.objects.filter(Q(attr1=True) | Q(attr2=True) | Q(attr3=True)).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)}

class HeadModel(models.Model):
    mtm = models.ManyToManyField(
        MyModel,
        limit_choices_to=my_func,
    )
```

P.S: yes, it is a very old post, but the need is/was still here

Answer (score 2):

`limit_choices_to` isn't being passed [a valid value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Comment: Can you explain that a little more pls?

Comment: I can't explain it any better than the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little bit old, but if you want to do a complex query( eg: nested foreign key filtering ) you can use class [`models.Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and directly assign to `limit_choices_to`

from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

> `limit_choices_to` **is or returns a Q object**, which is useful for
>   complex queries

**Example :**

```
from django.db import models


class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model_1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

class Model3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model_2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, limit_choices_to=models.Q(model_1__is_active=True))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)
```