# Choose queryset for limit_choices_to based on object fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to limit the choices of a foreign field to those other objects who look like the object self.

I've tried this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Model2, limit_choices_to='get_limit_choices_to')
    number = IntegerField()

    def get_limit_choices_to(self):
        return Model2.objects.filter(expenditure_type=self.expenditure_type)

class Model2(models.Model):
    number = IntegerField()
```

but I get the error

```
_filter_or_exclude() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

I don't know if limit_choices_to is the right way to do this. Maybe I should choose the queryset in a or the views.

The error says that `limit_choices_to='get_limit_choices_to'` is a wrong way to refer to the method, but how can I refer to the method correctly? I can't use

```
limit_choices_to=lambda: {'model1_set': self}
```

nor

```
limit_choices_to=lambda: {'number': number}
```

I am using Django 1.7.

Comment: note that the callable in the `limit_choices_to` needs to return a Q object or a dictionary..

Comment: I've tried changing my queryset to `Model2.objects.filter(expenditure_type=self.expenditure_type)`, but
it makes no difference.

Comment: how about letting the overlaying form take care of the choices altogether instead of the model itself... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589190/can-we-give-dynamic-queryset-for-modelchoicefield-in-django-forms/22590985#22590985

Answer (score -4):

Your function should be before the model. And should return an dictionary

```
def get_limit_choices_to():
    return {'entry': Model2.objects.get(number=1).id}

class Model1(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Model2, limit_choices_to=get_limit_choices_to)
    number = IntegerField()

class Model2(models.Model):
    number = IntegerField()
```