# Filtering a ContentType ForeignKey using django-polymorphic

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a bunch of Django models that inherit from django-polymorphic's Polymorphic model. In another model, I have a ForeignKey relation to ContentType which I'd like to limit to models that inherit from a specific base class.

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class MagicBaseModel(PolymorphicModel):
    def do_magic(self):
        # ...

class MagicObjectA(MagicBaseModel):
    def do_magic(self):
        super(MagicObjectA, self).do_magic(self)
        # ...

class MagicObjectB(MagicBaseModel):
    def do_magic(self):
        super(MagicObjectB, self).do_magic(self)
        # ...

class NonMagicObject(models.Model):
    # ...

class MagicAction(models.Model):
    magic_object_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    # ...
```

In the example above, I'd like to restrict MagicAction.magic_object_type so that only MagicObjectA and MagicObjectB are available as choices.

I've tried using `limit_choices_to` like this:

```
magic_object_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=Q(polymorphic_ctype=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MagicBaseModel)))
```

However, it seems you can't execute that query during model initialisation as the ContentType model isn't ready yet.

Any ideas of a better way I could approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following, inspired from here: [Choose queryset for limit_choices_to based on object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597521/choose-queryset-for-limit-choices-to-based-on-object-fields):

Your query for the two content types cannot yet be evaluated in the ForeignKey function, since the db will not yet be ready.

Therefore, you need to use a function instead, which will fetch the two choices for you when needed.

Then, in that function, you can filter on the 'model' field of the content type instance.

Like so:

```
def get_choices():
    query_a = ContentType.objects.filter(
        model=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MagicObjectA).model)
    query_b = ContentType.objects.filter(
        model=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MagicObjectB).model)
    return {'magic_object_type': query_a | query_b}
```

Where in your field declaration you can refer to this function, like so:

```
magic_object_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=get_choices)
```